# Detect how many columns that have come in via RCP

Tags: datastage

Is there a way to detect how many columns that have come in via RCP?   I have a Sequential File stage using RCP.  The next stage is a Transformer stage.  In the Transformer stage I want to know/detect the total number of columns coming from the Sequential File stage.  Is this possible?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking to do is not possible, unless you load the count from the schema file into a job parameter to which the Transformer stage has access.

Comment: Thanks so much Ray.  I'll take that approach.